# Break line in json string java

Tags: java, android, json

Don't know how to express myslef very well.As you see down in my code I have a String,an ArrayList of Strings and a spinner.

In my code I add the elements of my String in my ArrayList and then in my spinner. All good,except the fact that everything is on a single line,and I want each of the elements ("one,two,three,four") in a new line.

Note: I do not know what String accounts contain and how many values it has in it.

```
ArrayList<String> spinnerAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
String accounts = "one two three four";
Spinner accounts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accounts);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerAccounts);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        accounts.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerAccounts.add(System.lineSeparator());
                spinnerAccounts.add(accountID.toString());
```

Comment: Why are you creating an ArrayList `array` and not using it? Of course it is everything in one line, because you have only one String.

Comment: where you declared `spinnerAccounts` and what it contains??

Comment: I have updated the code.My bad

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 ArrayList<String> spinnerAccounts = new ArrayList<>(); // I don't know the use of this ArrayList
 Spinner accounts = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accounts);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
       new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinnerAccounts);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 accounts.setAdapter(adapter);
 spinnerAccounts.add("one");
 spinnerAccounts.add("two");
 spinnerAccounts.add("three");
 spinnerAccounts.add("four");
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> Add items you want to display in `Spinner` using `spinnerAccounts.add("ACCOUNT_NAME")` method.

Hope It'll help you.

Comment: Tried that,it doesn't suit my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding account names.

Comment: How can I do that when I don't know what String accounts contains and the length of it?

Comment: from where you get the `String accounts = "one two three four";`?

Comment: I recive the accounts String from a post method.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your string which will be shown in spinner like this

```
StringBuffer accounts = new StringBuffer("one");
stringBuffer.append("\n");
stringBuffer.append("two");
stringBuffer.append("\n");
stringBuffer.append("three");
stringBuffer.append("\n");
stringBuffer.append("four");
```

`TextView` in the spinner will populate the values in different lines provided height and width is `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Change u r code "accounts" used two times. Make arraylist for accounts and load into spinner.

```
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> accountsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    accountsList.add("one");
    accountsList.add("two");
    accountsList.add("three");
    accountsList.add("four");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                 (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,accountsList);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                 (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    // Spinner item selection Listener  
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    // Button click Listener 
    addListenerOnButton();
```

Follow this [Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82)